# issue when my last word of a text excerpt have accents (strange chars)

Tags: php, search

I'm doing a search system and in this system Im showing the search results but also a bit of text wich begins with searched word.

But Im having one problem and Im not how to solve it.

The problem is: When I search for some word and the last word of my text excert have a accent that last word appears strange or I have this "&" or �".

Can you please help me understand what is wrong here?

**My issue code:**

```
$search = $url[1];
$read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? LIMIT ?,?"); 
$read->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$read->bindValue(2, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$read->bindParam(3, $begin,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$read->bindParam(4, $max,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$read->execute();
$searchPos = stripos($result['content'],$search);
$searchLen = strlen($search);
$result_text = '"'.substr($result['content'], $searchPos, $searchLen + 35).'..."';
echo '<p>'.strip_tags($result_text).'</p>';
```

(And im using tinymce editor to insert in database)

To insert content in database using tinymce Im doing like this:

```
$f['content'] =$_POST['content'];
```

Then I insert like:

```
$insert->bindParam(4,$f['content']);
```

Comment: What kind of encoding are you using in your DB/table?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im using "utf8_general_ci".

Comment: are you sure its not in the database with the html elements?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dragon. I have because Im using tinymce editor to insert in my database. But then Im using strip_tags to show the text. And I think that strip_tags solve this, no?

Comment: strip tags does not remove html Entities, they should display in html just fine - uless doubly encoded - view source to check

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dagon. So how do you think I can remove this chars of my text result?

Comment: view web page souce is it showing `&amp;aacute;` ??

Comment: And this looks so stupid really. I search for "aluno" and I get my  � in my "história" word. But if I search for "alunos" my word appears correctly "História" without �!!

Comment: your encoding the html Entities twice which is why the `&` is being coverted to `&amp;` and the you see the code for the Entitie and not the character you want in the html.

Comment: Thanks for youra answer Dagon. But, where Im encoding html entities twice?

Comment: First make sure the characters are stored as UTF-8 characters in the database. Inspect the data with a db viewer. TinyMCE can convert them to entities, see http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're working with multibyte UTF-8 strings using non-multibyte functions.

Here's your code modified to work properly with UTF-8:

```
$search = $url[1];
$read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? LIMIT ?,?"); 
$read->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$read->bindValue(2, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$read->bindParam(3, $begin,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$read->bindParam(4, $max,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$read->execute();
$searchPos = mb_stripos($result['content'],$search,0,'utf-8');
$searchLen = mb_strlen($search,'utf-8');
$result_text = '"'.mb_substr($result['content'], $searchPos, $searchLen + 35, 'utf-8').'..."';
echo '<p>'.strip_tags($result_text).'</p>';
```

Note `mb_*` functions usage:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: That's the only answer that nails it. All others are completely not to the point..

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure your files are saved in utf-8 (utf-8 without BOM) encoding, any advanced editor will have the option to change file encoding, notepad++ has this option in its main menu.
2. Make sure your tables encoding is utf8 such as utf8_general_ci
3. Add the charset=utf8 in your dabatase connection string or if you are using php 5.3.6 or older use 'SET NAMES utf8' before your queries.
4. Set the character encoding in your php header, html, etc.
5. Use the php multibyte string functions for string search, comparition and such.

Optons 1, 3 and 5 will solve this issue for the most part.

Answer (score -1):

On the last line in the script use the htmlentities function.

```
echo '<p>'.htmlentities($result_text,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8").'</p>';
```

This should solve the 'weird character' problem :P